# Angular APP_INITIALIZER and beforeunload function on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile

I have two problems that only appear on mobile phones.

1. In Angular 9 application I have an APP_INITIALIZER provider which fires when the application is opened.The problem is on mobile, because on mobile if I close the browser and then reopen it, it will start with the same tabs, but the APP_INITIALIZER function will not be called.
2. I have two listeners: **window:beforeunload** and **window:unload**, both do the same thing (send a req to server), but the problem is that they don't always fire on mobile.

Comment: 1. Do the configurations or data created with APP_INITIALIZER also remain?
2. Add some code of these.

Comment: APP INITIALIZER sends a request and receives some data